# Div limit for a website

Tags: html

How many divs can you have on a webpage at one time? And what would be controlling that limit?

Comment: Depends on browser. And that is very strange question.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Would be useful to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282603/how-many-div-tags-are-too-much

Comment: I was not trying to solve a problem just yet. I was just curious.

Comment: The reason I asked is because our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) states: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"

Comment: Thank you for that Oded. I will take the FAQ's into account in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a hard limit in any modern browser. I've literally iterated and printed thousands of divs on pages before. Your real limiting factors are going to be how big you want your page to be and of course, eventually your page will take a very long time to load.

I just ran a test case where I inserted 2,097,152 divs in a page and though it was slow to respond, it did eventually come up without choking either IE or Chrome.

If you need more information, or perhaps help figuring out an approach that wouldn't take so many divs as to require this question, just let us know.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing limiting the number of divs on a website (other than the memory on your machine).

Comment: So, you could have an infinite number of divs displayed at one time?

Comment: @ocat - If you have infinite memory, sure.

Comment: @ocat If your computer has infinite memory and your processor has infinite speed (the browser has to parse HTML too), you could. But a 32bit SO can only handle 4GB RAM, so you will need an infinite-bit SO and a compiler which compiles the browser's source code to an infine-bit program.